# Is inverse sufficient for a semigroup to be a group?

Tags: group-theory, semigroups

If $(A,\cdot)$ is a set with a closed operation ( $a,b\in A \rightarrow a\cdot b\in A$) and associative demanding it to be inverse (from both left and right) must make it a group? as we must have identity element by the definition of inverse ($a\cdot a^{-1}=1$) so we "get the identity for free"?

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your question properly, but if you are speaking of inverses, you must have an identity to begin with.

Comment: How do you define the notion of inverse if there's no identity element? Isn't the (right) inverse of $a$ defined as the unique solution to $ab=1$?

Comment: @OlivierMoschetta Will this work? Given $g$ there is a $g_1$ such that $gg_1h=h$ for all $h\in G$

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one other stipulation: that $A$ is *nonempty*. The other properties hold vaccuously otherwise but are not sufficient for $(A, \cdot)$ to be a group.

Once there is an $a\in A$, then, by inverses, there exists an $a^{-1}\in A$ that, moreover, multiplies with $a$ to, indeed, get an identity element.

---

Contrary to what is said in the comments, one can have (at least a modified form of) inverses without an identity. An inverse semigroup $S$ is one in which for all $s\in S$ there exists a $t\in S$ such that $s=sts$ and $t=tst$ (and idempotents commute).